# Error when I try to run npm install

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I'm just trying to do the first angular.js tutorial on the official website. When I try to run npm install from my project directory I get the following error.

[image]

My package.json file is given below.

```js
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "name": "angular-phonecat",
  "description": "A tutorial application for AngularJS",
  "repository": "https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "karma": "^0.12.16",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.1.5",
    "protractor": "~1.0.0",
    "http-server": "^0.6.1",
    "tmp": "0.0.23",
    "bower": "^1.3.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.2.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",

    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000",

    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "node node_modules/karma/bin/karma start test/karma.conf.js",
    "test-single-run": "node node_modules/karma/bin/karma start test/karma.conf.js  --single-run",

    "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",

    "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver",
    "protractor": "protractor test/protractor-conf.js",

    "update-index-async": "node -e \"require('shelljs/global'); sed('-i', /\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_START@@[\\s\\S]*\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_END@@/, '//@@NG_LOADER_START@@\\n' + cat('bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js') + '\\n//@@NG_LOADER_END@@', 'app/index-async.html');\""
  }
}
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: try without the sudo, you shouldn't need it for local project  packages

Comment: @MichaelColeman just tried it. But I get the same error :-(.

Comment: you should be getting a folder called `node_modules` which contain all the downloaded packages , are you getting that?

Comment: Yes node_modules is in my project folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The messages are warnings, sometimes that just happens, and they often are uneeded anyway.
As long as the main components, Bower, Protractor, Karma etc are working, then I would try just carry on with the tutorial.

You can test they are working by running their commands, e.g.

```
./node_modules/.bin/bower help
```

#### But

I think one issue I had with npm and running those commands is that they dont just run like the angular tutorial says.
So where the tutorial says, run this:

```
protractor test/protractor-conf.js
```

You might have to modify the command to this

```
./node_modules/.bin/protractor test/protractor-conf.js
```

Same with bower, karma etc

e.g.

put this in front of the commands

```
./node_modules./bin
```

the `./` says run this as a script and the path is so you access the scripts in the `node_modules/.bin` directories

**Update**
If you want to run a karma test:
First, make sure **you are in the root directory** of the project

```
./node_modules/.bin/karma start test/karma.conf.js  --single-run
```

Comment: bower help works. But when I try to start Karma by running: npm test, I get an error. So I tried the command "karma" inside the ./node_modules./bin too. But no luck.